# Compare bit with parity

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

What is the most efficient way to compare a flag (0x00010001) bitwise with an integer and see if both the bit in integer is set ?

In other words what is the most efficient way to perform following ?

```
        bit = (number & 0x001 ) &  (number 0x 0x00010000 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with

```
(number & 0x00010001) == 0x00010001
```

which will be true if and only if both bits in `number` are set.

Comment: Does this one is more expensive than the one suggested by @nhahtdh with respect to performance. All bits needs to be compared after and operation?

Comment: @tectrendz: If there is any difference, it is hardly a problem with today's hardware.

Comment: The computer should perform one integer operation (`&`) and one logical operation (`==`) rather than a bunch of bit operations.  @nhahtdh's answer uses two integer operations (`~`, `&`) and one logical operation (`!`).  There may be no difference, though, as `!` is likely to be a free byproduct of `&`.

Answer (score 4):

A succinct solution, which is extensible to any number of bits you want to test simultaneously on:

```
!(~number & 0x00010001)
```

I invert all the bits of `number` with bitwise NOT. If both bits are set, both bits will now be 0, and bitwise AND `&` with the mask will result in 0. Apply logical NOT to 0 will return non-zero integer.

If any of the bits is 0, inverting the bit will make it 1. So the result after bitwise AND will be non-zero, and logical NOT of non-zero integer will return 0.

Comment: if you choose this method, please put it behind a macro or inline function with a nice name so whoever needs to read it later won't have to puzzle it out.